# relevel factor with different values' groups based on other column values

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to render a table and I need to order or relevel one column based on the values of the other column, so that I get the correct order for each value of the second column.

here is and example:

```
perc_type <- c('100%: a', '200%: a', '300%: a', '50%: a', '100%: bx', '200%: bx', '300%: bx', '50%: bx',
               '100%: cy', '200%:cy', '300%: cy', '50%: cy' )
country <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c')

test <- data.frame(perc_type, country)
```

Now I am getting this:

```
perc_type  country
100%: a     A
200%: a     A
300%: a     A
50%: a      A
100%: bx    B
200%: bx    B
300%: bx    B
50%: bx     B
```

but I would like that for each letter the order would be with increasing percentage 50% 100% 200% 300%,
is it possible to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may extract the numeric value from `perc_type` column and use it in `order` to get the required order.

In base R, you can do that as following -

```
test[with(test, order(country, as.integer(sub('%.*', '', perc_type)))), ]

#   perc_type country
#4     50%: a       A
#1    100%: a       A
#2    200%: a       A
#3    300%: a       A
#8    50%: bx       B
#5   100%: bx       B
#6   200%: bx       B
#7   300%: bx       B
#12   50%: cy       c
#9   100%: cy       c
#10   200%:cy       c
#11  300%: cy       c
```

where `sub('%.*', '', perc_type)` drops everything after a `"%"` sign so we are only left with numbers.

---

Using `dplyr`, here is another option -

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  mutate(perc_value = readr::parse_number(perc_type)) %>%
  arrange(country, perc_value)
```